# Can I edit the information placed on a RFID chip with the ISO 14443-4 Type A?

Tags: smartcard, rfid, apdu, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

Can I edit the information placed on a RFID chip with the ISO 14443-4 Type A?
I’m trying to figure out if this is possible, and what hardware do I need to edit this type of chip, however, I can’t find that much information when doing research.

Comment: When you are talking about ISO 14443-4 then you are talking about close distance cards running at ~13MHz. Many RFID **tags** are running at longer distance and 125KHz. Furthermore, the ISO 14443-4 is a relatively complex protocol that is more common for memory cards (MIFARE, DESFire etc.) and full fledged smart cards that handle APDU's. Any PCSC (PC to smartcard) reader can be used for the latter. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The communication protocol (ISO 14443-4 Type A) gives little to no indication, what the chip behind is capable of. If it is a full smartcard (or a DESFire) some knowledge of the relevant keys will be necessary; even if you are technically able, to update the information, you may not be allowed to do it.